# Set UIBarButtonItem to a UIBarButtonSystemItem programmatically

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem

Can I assign a system item to a `UIBarButtonItem` without having to recreate it? Just calling [initWithBarButtonSystemItem](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIBarButtonItem/initWithBarButtonSystemItem%3atarget%3aaction%3a) on the existing button doesn't seem to work for me.

[This](https://github.com/zSprawl/NativeControls/blob/044a147e2469212a3524c897e5fd634bf5a129ed/Cordova/Plugins/NativeControls.m#L473) is the code in which I try to make it work. I'm trying to improve native controls support for iOS using PhoneGap. That plugin allows changing title/image without problems but I have to figure out how to assign a system-provided icon to the existing button.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I took a look at your code, didn't find your use of `initWithBarButtonSystemItem`. However, this is what I'm doing in a similar case with native iOS programming:

```
UIBarButtonItem *myButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(done)];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = myButton;
[myButton release];
```

This works correctly for me.  I'm not familiar with PhoneGap and it may or may not change things however.

Comment: Nice, assigning a new button like this works as expected. Thanks!